# Dojo DataGrid and column resize

Tags: javascript, datagrid, dojo

In Dojo's DataGrid, is it possible to make all columns resizable, while having the Grid automatically to 100% width? Specifying the column widths in percentages would be perfect, but this is not supported. I can have the DataGrid extend 100% only if columns are set to "auto" but in this case they are not resizable and this is probably not going to be supported in the future, at least according to the official docs.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to checkout dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid. It does support percentages as a width unit and is based on dojox.grid.DataGrid. Also it has a plugin system so you can add more functionality when desired.

Answer (score 0):

The new **dojo** component **dgrid** supports setting width of the whole table to auto and then widths of each column separately as percentages.

http://dojofoundation.org/packages/dgrid/